# How to make absolute positioning images to stay fixed like background-attachment: fixed;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I use [backstretch.js](https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch) for cross browser background images cover. How can I set to that images stay fixed on certain block like `background-attachment: fixed` ?

I know that there is a jQuery way to set background-image positioning fixed cross browser

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
  $('.first-block').css('background-position', 'center ' + ((scrolledY)) + 'px');
});
```

But that code freezes in Mac OS and iOS.. Is there any method to add that code to images not for background images? Or is that any method to remove that freezes..? If there not freezes i'll delete backstretch.js and make my scrolling with background images..

[JSFIDDLE DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/5yday19t/1/) On this demo you can see emulating `background-position: fixed` with jQuery. It freezes on Mac OS and iOS. On windows its fine! How can I remove that freezes?

[JSFIDDLE DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/5yday19t/4/) On this demo you can see action with backstretch.js which makes full size images cross browser. How can I set it to scroll like in DEMO 1 ?

Comment: You mean have the images fixed in place?

Comment: you mean like .image{position:fixed; top:xxx; left:xxx}? If not, please add some code or example

Comment: I mean make some parallax effect like it do background-position: fixed. But not with background-image and `<img>` Okay I'll add jsfiddle, give me a few minutes